# Numpy error - windows 10

Tags: python, windows, numpy

I have already installed python2.7 from python.org (the 32-bit edition even though I use 64-bit Windows 10), the numpy from sourceforge and the matplotlib by running : pip install matplotlib. Now I want to run a code from command line with the following command: python2.7 fft.py FFT.in n dt

where fft.py : is the code file which applies the Time Fourier Transform on a velocity component

FFT.in : is the input files which includes the velocity values through time

n : is the the column of this file in which we want to apply the transform

and dt : is the time step of the fourier transform.

So, although python seems to work properly, (for example when I type simple commands in python command line), when i run the above command in cmd command line in the specific folder that all these files are located, I get an error about numpy "ImportError No module named numpy ".

I have also set the enviroment variables so they include python's path and python script's path.

Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Thank you in advance for your help.

This is the code included in fft.py:

```
#/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib 
import sys

#matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 18})
#time,c1,c2,c3=np.loadtxt('stripl01_28.dat',usecols=(0,11,16,21),unpack=True)
#timestep=time[1]-time[0]
inp=sys.argv
fname=inp[1]
col=int(inp[2],10)
print col
a1,a2=np.loadtxt(fname,usecols=(col,0),unpack=True)
timestep=float(inp[3])
#omega=2*np.pi/(180*timestep)
#print omega  
#k1=c1**2+c2**2+c3**2
#k11=c11**2+c22**2+c33**2

#fig1 = plt.figure(facecolor='white')
#ax = fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)
#plt.xlim(0.001,10)
#ax.set_yscale('log')
#ax.set_xscale('log')
#plt.xlabel('f [Hz]',fontsize=20)
#plt.ylabel('S',fontsize=20)
#plt.grid('on')

k1=a1
fft=np.fft.fft(k1)
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(k1.size,d=timestep)
a=np.sqrt(fft.real**2+fft.imag**2)


b=freq>0 
plt.plot(freq[b],a[b],label='t=1')
X=np.column_stack((freq[b],a[b]))
np.savetxt("fft.dat",X,fmt='%.18e',delimiter=' ')
```

Comment: Can you show the code in your `fft.py` file? Do you have `numpy` installed? `pip install numpy` Do you have `import numpy` at the beginning of your code?

Comment: I have already installed numpy. When i type import numpy in python shell it does not give an error as feedback.

Comment: I edited my post above and included the code. Sorry I'm new in this foroum and I can't handle very well the format of my posts yet.

Comment: The problem seems to appear only in cmd and not in python sell. But in python shell i don't know how to run it.

Comment: For being able to run your scipt in Python shell you have to [put it in a function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) (the complete tutorial is actually quite good) - for passing command-line arguments to programs I would strongly suggest using the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module.

Comment: You can make sure your code is not executed on import by putting it in a `if __name__=="__main__":` block.

Comment: Actually I'm not a python user. I usually write fortran codes. So could you please explain a little bit more how could I check this?

Comment: Regarding the error about numpy not being installed, your note that numpy was installed from sourceforge and not via pip makes it possible numpy wasn't installed correctly, from windows `cmd` type `pip freeze` and check that `numpy` is in the output list of installed python packages. If it is not, issue the pip command to install numpy, same as you did for matplotlob, except it'll be `pip install numpy`, see then if pip successfully installs numpy and you don't get that error again.

Comment: i just typed pip freeze and it returns numpy as an output. What elscould be wrong? I really can't find out.

Comment: That's good progress. Do you still get the "numpy not installed" or any errors when you run `python2.7 fft.py FFT.in n dt` from the command line? What about removing the `2.7` and just use `python fft.py FFT.in n dt`?

Comment: It just worked. I just removed the 2.7 from the command and it just worked. Thank you very much for your help and your time! I really thank you!